# How to see tensorflow build configuration?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to build tensorflow from source on a remote server (with no superuser privileges) because I got this error when I simply installed with pip:

```
Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.1.2 but source was compiled with: 7.4.2.  CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
```

I completed all the steps listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) successfully, but I still get the same error as above, despite setting CudNN version as 7.1.2 before building.

Is there any way I can see the configurations to verify that they have been set properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file is generated after running `./configure` with the name `.tf_configure.bazelrc` you can inspect that file.

Comment: Is there is way to the same if you are not the build owner ? meaning I have only the .whl file ?